# Flex grow not extending contents of div to fit full width of the div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to have the input elements take up the entire allotted width, however, for some reason, it just remains the default size that it is initially rendered with.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-panini-m6eh9?file=/src/App.js)

I'm able to remedy this by doing,

```
. . .
<input style={{ width: '100%' }}
. . .
```

but I was under the impression that flex grow would do this for me.

I've also tried doing `flexBasis: '100%'` instead of `flexGrow: 1`, but that seemed to yield the same result as the latter.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, is explicitly setting the width on the input the only way to get it to change width?

Expected output:
[image: img]

Comment: The code really should be posted *here* instead of on some external site.

Comment: Set the width of the input elements to 100%, 100% refers to 100% of the parent element

Comment: I've added the expect output

Comment: @PeterSH Yeah, I wrote that in the question. I'm assuming that's the only way to get it to be full width? Can't use flex for that?

Answer (score 2):

To make `input` elements take as much space as possible in the flex container, you can use one of the following options:

1. Set width on the input elements. When you set `flex-basis` or `flex-grow`, you are setting that on the container of the input element, not the `input` itself. So the container grows in size, not the input.

```js
const Input = ({ label }) => (
  <div className="inputContainer">
    <div>{label}</div>
    <input />
  </div>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Input label="First Input" />
      <Input label="Second Input" />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.container { display: flex; }
.inputContainer { flex-grow: 1; }

.inputContainer input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

2. Another way to achieve the desired layout is that you can make the input container a flex container and then set flex-grow or flex-basis on the `div` element that is wrappred around the `label` and the `input` element.

   ```js
   const Input = ({ label }) => (
     <div className="inputContainer">
       <div>
         <label>{label}</label>
         <input />
       </div>
     </div>
   );

   function App() {
     return (
       <div className="container">
         <Input label="First Input" />
         <Input label="Second Input" />
       </div>
     );
   }

   ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
   ```

   ```css
   .container,
   .inputContainer, 
   .inputContainer div {
     display: flex;
   }

   .inputContainer {
     flex-grow: 1;
   }

   .inputContainer div {
     flex-direction: column;
     flex-grow: 1;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
   <div id="root"></div>
   ```